# Can find command be run with two OR'd -name values?

Tags: bash

I need to use the Linux `find` command so that I can search for one name or the other.

I need a way to find two files that are transferred from MS Windows applications. One is produced with a .csv extension, and the other has a .CSV extension. They also have spaces in the file names, which I know how to handle.

However, but I am not quite sure how to add .CSV to the `-name \*.csv` parameter of the following`find` command.

Can two values be OR'd in the `-name` parameter?

```
for fnam in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.csv -exec echo "{}" \;` 
do
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command should find both types of files. Please note the escape characters and spaces after parentheses.

`find . \( -name "*.cvs" -o -name "*.CVS" \)`

Comment: Where is -o in the docs? I've looked under man and on the web.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, it's under `OPERATORS` section in `man find`

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear, why are you not using the `-iname '*-csv'` option?

Answer (score 1):

Change the find part of your script to be this?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name \*.csv -o -name \*.CSV \) -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just matching the extensions .csv and .CSV, you might as well use globbing instead of `find`, i.e.

```
for fnam in *.csv *.CSV; do
    ...
```